# Secondary Domain Controller

Tags: windows

I have 2 physical servers srvr1 and srvr2 running windows server 2012 Standard, with 32GiB RAM and 800GB for each.  srvr1  is a Domain controller and I need to make secondary as backup in case the first one fails.

My question is what is the best option?

Install secondary domain on Srvr2 or on the hyper instance of srvr2 and why

Comment: Those seem to be quite under-utilized for domain controllers...a DC needs ~2 GB of RAM at most (and that's mostly for the OS anyway).

Comment: RAM should be "the recommendation is to reference the basic operating system hardware requirements, plus recommendations for third-party software (antivirus, systems management, and so on), and the NTDS.DIT and SYSVOL sizes" according to [MS](http://tinyurl.com/oasxcrb). Win Server 2008 and newer can live in ~256MB, that much more for AV and Mgmt tools, plus NTDS and SYSVOL (usually <100MB in a small environment; could be large in an enterprise), for a total of 512-768MB.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine what kind of capacity requires this kind of provisioning, especially with server 2012 core.  Also, consider upgrading to server 2012 R2 for new installations, especially for DCs - AD is always backwards compatible many, many versions.

You should be using these physical servers to run hyper-v or another hypervisor, and nothing else.  Make small VMs for the domain controllers (there aren't primary and secondary ones anymore, just domain controllers, though there are some FSMO roles).  The small VMs will require 1-4GB of RAM and some disk, and 1-2 cores, usually, depending on your specific scenario.

Since you're trying to protect against hardware failures (I assume), you should obviously put them on separate physical hosts.  That's all, really.